# FileUpload.HasFile incorrectly returning false

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

The ASP control `FileUpload` is always returning `false` for the method `FileUpload.HasFile`. I have tried using a trigger but that did not work for me.

here is the button method

```
protected void btnUploadFile_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  testMethod();
}
```

Here is the `testMethod()` the if statement is always evaluating to false.

```
protected void testMethod()
{
  if(FileUploadImage.HasFile)
  {
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "NoDatabaseAlertMessage", "alert('it work')", true);
  }
  else
  {
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "NoDatabaseAlertMessage", "alert('no work')", true);
  }
}
```

Edit1: here is the html trigger stuff i tried to implement, was unsuccessful

```html
<div>
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
      <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUploadFile" />
    </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>

  <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadImage" runat="server" />

  <asp:Button ID="btnUploadFile" runat="server" Text="Upload File" class="btn btn-primary transition-3d-hover" OnClick="btnUploadFile_Clicked" />

</div>
```

Comment: Is your FileUpload being reset on a Page.PostBack?  Edit: and String.Format() that text! So hard to look at...

Comment: @JohnPete22 I am not sure. how can I tell?

Comment: On the Page_Load event, is there any code that is setting the FileUpload value?  In short, when you click a button (i.e. Upload File), it's going to post back to the server and hit Page_Load again before it runs the button click event, so if you have code that is defaulting the FileUpload field (not wrapped in a !Page.IsPostBack check) then that default will get reset and you won't have the file still present in there that was wanting to be uploaded.

Comment: Again, this is just a *thought*  -- this is the first thing I check if I lose a value (in a textbox, grid, etc..) after hitting a button click and posting back when I think I should still have that value present.

Comment: @JohnPete22 there is currently no code in my Page_Load method. Can you expand on the 'wrapped in a !Page.IsPostBack check' it sounds like that might be it?  let me know

Comment: @griffin_cosgrove The questions all revolve around how you're calling the `renameFilePath` method. Please include that in your question or we'll all be guessing. Also, you said you tried using a trigger. If the upload ctrl is in an update panel, it won't work. They are not designed to work in update panels.

Comment: Could you post your FileUpload button click code? Try FileUpload.HasFile instead of FileUploadImage.Has.File.

Comment: @wazz I will try again and verify that it will not be in a update panel. I will also edit my post to include more code that you have requested

Comment: @KHS there is one button on this form that commits several textboxes and dropdowns to a database, so the method is lengthy. I can try to separate it out for the purpose of debugging.

Comment: I don't see your button to pass the FileUpload value (same as @JohnPete22). Eventually, you should get: `var file = FileUploadImage.FileName;`

Comment: Try FileUploadImage.PostedFile != null. That's what works on my image uploads.

Comment: @KHS that is part of the problem, ```FileUploadImage.PostedFile``` and ```FileUploadImage.PostedFile.FileName``` always = null for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that someone on my team made a bad edit to the code in the .aspx file and did not close a form tag. After I closed the form tag, the issues went away and the control behaved as expected.